# Hide Columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `GridView` which I fill with a `DataTable` on RunTime, but I want to hide one of the columns when it's already loaded in the `GridView`, I've tried:

```
Me.GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
```

but it gives me an exception of Out of range.

Do you know any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you show some more code and give details about how and where are you defining your gridview and its columns, assigning datatable to gridview and where setting visible = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
    GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping, I tried grid.ros.cells(i).visible = false but it did not worked but reading I found that I have to hide the header row too, so I made this function to hide any row in any grid

```
Private Sub HideColumn(ByRef grid As GridView, ByVal x As Integer)
    If grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        grid.HeaderRow().Cells(x).Visible = False
        For i As Integer = 0 To grid.Rows.Count - 1
            grid.Rows(i).Cells(x).Visible = False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```